# iphone: create array of strings in resource file

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, resources

Hi I don't know how to to do this in iphone. I have google around but haven't found anything. I would like to create 2 arrays for my app in resource files (like the String resource) and load them in code when I need them. I can't find a way to create such a file nor code to load from resources files something similar to:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"seleccion2", @"Localization", nil)
```

but for arrays. if someone could point me to a tutorial.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` and `[NSArray initWithContentsOfFile:]` should be what you are looking for.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray